# Looping through elements not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to check if `this` element has a matching data attribute value to all other elements, but the loop doesn't always work.

Stripped down code below.

HTML

```
<div class="list">
   <div class="target" data-post-id="1"></div>
   <div class="target" data-post-id="2"></div>
   <div class="target" data-post-id="1"></div>
   <div class="target" data-post-id="1"></div>
</div>
```

JS (event is tied to the `target` class):

```
if ($(this).data("post-id") == $(this).closest('.list').find('.target').data("post-id")) {
   // do stuff
}
```

Clearly, I don't know how to loop through it properly. What's the solution?

Comment: Do all of the elements have to have the same `id` for this to be true?

Comment: "Not working" how? Throwing an error? Just not working how you intend?

Comment: @CarlEdwards No, the aim is to avoid *doing stuff* if the data value is not matching. Hence the if statement.

Comment: @jeffdill2 Sometimes, the if statement goes through *even* if the data values are not matching. Don't think I am looping properly.

Comment: @HenrikPetterson So basically, only elements of the same `id` do certain things amongst each other, correct?

Comment: `$(this).closest('.list').find('.target').data("post-id")` does not compare every thing to the if.... it only grabs the first one that matches....

Comment: @MisterPositive  Please post answer with loop solution. As far as I know, it iterates. But I could def be wrong.

Comment: @epascarello I think you are right, can you post answer to do a proper loop here?

Comment: filter() is what you need....

Comment: @Turnip I don't think I am looping properly. Can you please post answer.

Comment: I don't think I am looping properly" You have no loop in the code above

Comment: @epascarello Could you please post an answer demonstrating how to use `.filter()` in my scenario?

Comment: Wouldn't two `each()` loops suffice in this case?

Comment: Odd how there have been at least 5 answers posted and not a single one of them have posted a proper jQuery solution to the question...

Comment: @MisterPositive I'm not complaining. I am actually impressed that this is actually quite a good question!

Comment: $('.list').find('li').each(function () { /* your code here */ ) );

Comment: @epascarello Did you actually have a solution to this one? It appears all answers posted so far have been incorrect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could probably use a one-liner:

```
if ($(this).closest('.list').find('.target[data-post-id=' + $(this).data("post-id") + ']').not(this).length > 0) {
// there was at least one other element in the list with the same data-post-id as the clicked element
}
```

Comment: Super clean. Very nice. :thumbsup:

Answer (score 0):

I have an answer in pure javascript. Try this,

```js
var divs = document.getElementsByClassName('list')[0].children;
function divClick(element) {
 Array.from(divs).forEach(div => {
  if(element != div) {
    if (element.dataset.postId == div.dataset.postId) {
      console.log("equal");
    } else {
      console.log("not equal");
    }
    }
  }); 
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
   <div class="target" onclick="divClick(this)" data-post-id="1">One</div>
   <div class="target" onclick="divClick(this)" data-post-id="2">Two</div>
   <div class="target" onclick="divClick(this)" data-post-id="1">Three</div>
   <div class="target" onclick="divClick(this)" data-post-id="1">Four</div>
</div>
```

`.siblings()` in jquery will be helpful in this case,

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.target').click(function(){
     $.each($(this).siblings(), (div, element) => {
         if($(element).data("post-id") == $(this).data("post-id")) {
              console.log("Equal");
            } else {
              console.log("Not Equal");
            }
        })
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list">
   <div class="target" data-post-id="1">One</div>
   <div class="target" data-post-id="2">Two</div>
   <div class="target" data-post-id="1">Three</div>
   <div class="target" data-post-id="1">Four</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just tested your code via phpStorm and it is displaying errors: https://i.imgur.com/VW6O111.png

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

#### HTML

```
<div class="list">
  <div class="not-a-sibling">
    <div class="target" data-post-id="1"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="target" data-post-id="2"></div>
  <div class="not-a-target">I'M NOT A TARGET, LEAVE ME ALONE!</div>
  <div class="target" data-post-id="1"></div>
  <div class="target" data-post-id="1"></div>
  <div class="target" data-post-id="3"></div>
  <div class="target" data-post-id="3"></div>
</div>
```

---

*Assuming you're basing this on click event – obviously, change this to hover or whatever's relevant.*

#### JS (More verbose example)

```
$(document).on('click', '.target', function() {
  var clickedTarget = $(this);
  var clickedTargetPostId = clickedTarget.data('post-id');
  var elementsToCompare = clickedTarget.parents('.list').find('.target').not(this);

  elementsToCompare.each(function() {
    var elementToComparePostId = $(this).data('post-id');

    if (elementToComparePostId === clickedTargetPostId) {
      alert('Found a match!');
    }
  });
});
```

Test it out here:

https://jsfiddle.net/5wv40vq9/4/

#### JS (Less verbose)

```
$(document).on('click', '.target', function() {
  var _this = this;

  $(_this).parents('.list').find('.target').not(this).each(function() {
    if ($(this).data('post-id') === $(_this).data('post-id')) {
      alert('Found a match!');
    }
  });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5wv40vq9/5/

Comment: Testing your cod but it doesn't seem to execute? I added the missing `});` at the end with no results.

Comment: Sorry, fixed the closing `});`. Are you getting any errors in console?

Comment: Yes, `TypeError: elementsToCompare.forEach is not a function`

Comment: I'm fixing now. Sorry, I wasn't able to actually test earlier.

Comment: Thanks! Although is there any way to adjust it so it works if the divs aren't siblings, see example: https://jsfiddle.net/5wv40vq9/1/

Comment: Sure. Give me a minute to make a few adjustments.

Comment: OK, answer updated. FYI, I also added a couple more targets with different post IDs so you could see that it'll work correctly with any number of post IDs.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need something like this?

```
var arr1 = [];
var arr2 = [];
$(".target").each(function(){
        arr1.push($(this).data("post-id"));
});

$(".target").each(function(index){
        var newArray = arr1.slice();
    newArray.splice(index, 1); // remove index value from an array, so this index != match its own
            console.log(newArray);
    if ($.inArray($(this).data("post-id"), newArray ) !== -1){
            $(this).text("Has A Match!");
    }else{
            $(this).text("No Match!");
    }

});
```

Jsfiddle Here : https://jsfiddle.net/synz/votuqyp0/1/